# Getting error when executing initdb in container during pipeline build stage

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, jenkins, groovy, devops

I'm trying to initialize a new db cluster so that i can create a new db in container during pipeline build stage. i want to run a postgres db in container that interacts with webserver that will run in agent node. i have checked the permission of binary and it has executable permission for the user but still getting cannot execute binary file.

```
# Use the official AlmaLinux 8 image as the base image
FROM almalinux:8 

COPY tu_certs /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/tu_certs.crt 
RUN mkdir -p /etc/ssl/certs && cp /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/tu_certs.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
COPY tu_http_certs.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
RUN update-ca-trust extract

#Install PostgreSQL and its client 
RUN yum -y install postgresql-server 
sudo USER postgres 
  RUN /usr/bin/initdb /var/lib/pgsql/data/
  RUN /usr/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/pgsql/data -s -w && createdb test 
USER root
EXPOSE 5434

pipeline{
agent {

  kubernetes {

    cloud 'kubernetes-custstage'

    inheritFrom 'custstagek8s-slim'

    yaml """

      spec:

        containers:

          - name: controller-test-tools
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            image: artifactory.....com/docker-dev-local/controller-test-tools:latest
            tty: true
    """.stripIndent()
  }
}
stages {
   stage('Build') {
        steps {
            script{
            echo "Hello from the agent"
            sh 'uname -m'
            }
            container('controller-test-tools') {
                script {
                  echo ' inside container'
                   sh 'psql --version'
                  sh 'ls -l /usr/bin/initdb'
                  sh 'ls -l /usr/bin/createdb'
                  sh 'uname -m'
                  sh 'su postgres /usr/bin/initdb tps_data'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which binary file?